# Do we have a continuous function while nowhere VB

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking a example the a function is continuous on a closed bounded interval but nowhere bounded variation on the interval.

Comment: Do you know an example of a continuous function that is _somewhere_ not of bounded variation?

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt(x)sin(x)$is continuous but not bounded at any interval containing 0

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}\,\sin \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: yes. In fact, $f(x)=x^\alpha sin(x^{-\beta})\forall \alpha>\beta$, we have property you mentioned. But I want a function continuous but **nowhere** VB.

Comment: Yes, but starting out with a function that is of unbounded variation at one point, we can try to build one that has unbounded variation everywhere from it via translation.

Answer (score 0):

You want a continuous function that is not of bounded variation on any interval?  If you have learned Lebesgue's theorem then you can imagine the answer.  That theorem says that a function of bounded variation would have to have a derivative at almost every point.  Thus any continuous nowhere-differentiable function has the property you require.

Don't expect a simple formula for such a function.